# Suitable idiom for using instead of immunize

Tags: idioms

We have water that is not drinkable, we boil it for killing the microbes, is this sentence correct “I immunize the water ” or there is an idiom for this action?

Comment: The word is *sterilize*.

Comment: @PeterShor Also: disinfect.  (Technically sterilization implies removal of all life-forms, which boiling doesn't achieve.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you boil it to kill the microbes, you are sterilizing the water through [Sterilization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterilization_%28microbiology%29).

[Dictionary.com meaning:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sterilizing)

> ster·i·lize  [ster-uh-lahyz]
>   verb (used with object),
>
> ster·i·lized, ster·i·liz·ing.
>
> 1. to destroy microorganisms in or on, usually by bringing to a high temperature with steam, dry heat, or boiling liquid.
> 2. to destroy the ability of (a person or animal) to reproduce by removing the sex organs or inhibiting their functions.
> 3. to make (land) barren or unproductive.
> 4. Informal. to delete or remove anything comprising or damaging from: to sterilize a government document before releasing it to the press.
> 5. Informal. to isolate or completely protect from unwanted, unauthorized, or unwholesome activities, attitudes, influences, etc.:
>      You can't sterilize children against violence.

Answer (score 5):

And by *sterilizing* you are making the water [Potable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potable?s=t).

> fit or suitable for drinking: potable water.

Answer (score 1):

The [most common idiom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=water+safe+to+drink%2Cwater+fit+for+drinking%2Cwater+suitable+for+drinking%2Cwater+safe+for+drinking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwater%20safe%20to%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwater%20fit%20for%20drinking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwater%20suitable%20for%20drinking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwater%20safe%20for%20drinking%3B%2Cc0) for that action is "make water [safe to drink](http://www.survivalblog.com/2012/03/making-water-safe-to-drink-by-paratrooper-john.html)."

[Most residential coffee makers are not capable of maintaining high temperatures for a long enough period of time to make the water safe to drink.](http://www.healthunit.org/water/bwa_faq.html)

[Both steps are necessary to remove or kill all bacteria, viruses and parasites and make the water safe to drink.](http://healthvermont.gov/enviro/water/lake_river.aspx)

[How can you make the water safe to drink?](http://t.answers.com/answers/?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F#!/entry/dda46980910cf2a9613610f65ac79574&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.answers.com%2FQ%2FHow_can_you_make_water_safe_to_drink%23page1&oswts=1397572435891)

Answer (score 1):

The commonly used term for this is to "purify" the water; other options are: sanitize, disinfect or decontaminate.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) indicates, the best answers provide detailed explanation, with suitable references and links. I would note, for example, that *disinfect* and *decontaminate* refer to two different ways to *purify*; they are not interchangeable.